# Django Test request.method == 'POST' not working

Tags: python, django

I am working on an example in TDD with python and am trying to accept a post request.

Django's [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/) page for `HttpRequest.method` suggests using the following snippet to responde to GET and POST differently

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    do_something()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    do_something_else()
```

With this in mind, my view is setup like so:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from items.models import Item

def index_page(request):

    name = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['item']
        Item.objects.create(name=name)

    return render(request, 'items/index.html', {'item': name})
```

My test file contains the following

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest
from items.views import index_page
from items.models import Item

class IndexPageTest(TestCase):

    def test_index_page_can_save_a_post_request(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.POST['item'] = 'MyItem'
        response = index_page(request)

        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.first().name, 'MyItem')
```

Which yields the following error

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_index_page_can_save_a_post_request (items.tests.IndexPageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/items/tests.py", line 43, in test_index_page_can_save_a_post_request
    self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

However when I alter the view to the following, the test passes.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from items.models import Item

def index_page(request):

    name = request.POST.get('item', '')
    if name:
        Item.objects.create(name=name)

    return render(request, 'items/index.html', {'item': name})
```

Clearly, my page is repsonding to POST requests and the test is sending POST data, but I'm not sure why the `if request.method == 'POST':` line does not appear to work.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
$ django-admin --version
1.10.3
```

Comment: Also set the `request.method = 'POST'` as your first example is making check based on rquest method and you are not setting that up

Answer (score 1):

Your test *isn't* sending a post. You should use the RequestFactory rather than instantiating HttpRequest directly. Or even better, use the built in test client.

Comment: I'm looking into the client, but how would `name = request.POST.get('item', '')` be returning the correct value if the `HttpRequest` wasn't sending POST data?

Comment: Probably the test passes because you created request object yourself and added only `item` key to it. So when you pass that request to second view, it finds a value for `item`, as you specified it, and creates the Item object. But

Comment: Well, you added an item to request.POST, so of course that works. But that doesn't change the request method.